# SUBMIT certificate request - outside domain

Tags: encryption, certificate, windows-server-2003, cryptoapi

I need to submit a PKCS#10 certificate request to a certificate authority who is outside my domain. [This article in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms867026.aspx#certenroll_topic4) shows a way to submit certificate requests within a network using `ICertRequest2` COM object.

```
hr = CertRequest->Submit( CR_IN_ENCODEANY | CR_IN_FORMATANY, RequestStr,
                          AttributesStr, CAName, &Disp );
```

where

```
BSTR CAName = SysAllocString( L"COMPUTERNAME\\CA Name" );
```

My question is how do i submit my request progrmatically from the client who is outside the Domain.

I don't want to use the Microsoft web enrollment pages, as this needs to be a automated process.

My CA is 2003 Enterprise and client is XP SP3.

Any ideas please?

Thanks

Comment: You could copy the file to a domain member computer (or even the CA), and run a program from there...

Comment: @borelid This is something(a webservice) which, i will be doing finally, if there is no other option/established approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, this can be done in few ways

1. Manually with some audit procedures between the CA and the participating entity/user
2. Semi automatically using the MS windows provided web URL/enrolment page, certsrv
3. Write your own solution, say, a web service to liaise between user and the CA